# How to integrate Crashlytics with static library

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics

Whilst adding Crashlytics in the static library, run script is getting failed with following error:

"Crashlytics: Failed to Detect Build Environment

INFOPLIST_PATH value not found in environment
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1"

---

Run Script:

./Crashlytics.framework/run "API key"

---

Comment: I've never used it, but it looks like it wants an `Info.plist` file which a static library project doesn't have.  What are you trying to do?  Call Crashlytics code from the static library code?

Comment: Essentially I want to have independent crash reporting system for library. The otherway round is to assign the Crashlytics instance from dependent module to static library rather than starting the instance itself in static library, and with this approach all the crash report from library will be accumulated in the module :(

Comment: What does that script do?  If it sets-up up the project to include and link against the crashlytics library then you will have to set it up manually.  This excludes the linking part as you don't link static libraries with other libraries; rather that is done in the final executable.

Comment: Script links the project with the another mac crashlytics application which in turn responsible for automatically updating the crashlytics framework in project. I guess it's doing something more than that like updating .dsym file.

Comment: Try the crashlytics support if you haven't already. They have helped me with wierd stuff in the past.

Comment: Just wondering if you were able to find a solution for this; I am basically trying to do the same thing.

Comment: @Guven No, Crashlytics still doesn't support for the static lib. The Only way is to integrate Crashlytics with the application project.

Comment: Thank you @AshishBindal, I also wasn't able to figure out a way.

Answer (score 0):

From your static library project: Build Settings -> Framework Search Header -> Add Crashlytics.Framework path that is being used by your app.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to integrate with your parent projects (dependant on your static lib).

I think that CFBundleIdentifier in the plist is required to distinguish crashes from different apps. I was trying to overcome it by tweaking INFOPLIST_PATH build setting and copying plist from dependant project to the static library... No joy :)